# failed to apply border radius style into table

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a table that has a scrollbar in my angular app.

In the code below I'm adding a div with the help of the after selector to add a space between the scrollbar and table container.

Because the table parent element doesn't take the 'padding-right' style when the table content get overflowed.

But my issue is: When I apply border-radius style into the table it doesn't apply it. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

```css
.tableContainer {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    width: 1340px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin-left: 18px;
}

.tableContainer>table  {
    border-radius:20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.tableContainer>table th {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.tableContainer>table td {
    border: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tableContainer table::after  {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    right: -20px;
    top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableContainer">
    <table>
        <!--<thead class="bg-dark">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th *ngFor="let thead of tableHeader">{{thead}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>-->
        <tbody>
            <tr class="bg-dark">
                <th></th>
                <th *ngFor="let thead of tableHeader">{{thead}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let key of tableColumnKeys;let i=index;" [class.firstRow]="i == 0">
                <td>{{key}}</td>
                <td *ngFor="let data of tableColumn[key]">
                    {{data}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that the table is with border-radius but you don't have a border to the table so you can't see the effect

Answer (score 1):

@Paco Gómez Capón - I would also set `overflow: hidden` on `.tableContainer>table`
Otherwise the content will go over the rounded border. See image

[image]

Comment: I agree! But the main problem is solved with my solution. In fact, I am going to edit it! Thanks!

Comment: when am I adding 'overflow:hidden' property the element that I added using after selector will be removed.

Comment: Because you have it with right: -20px, it goes out of the box!

Answer (score 0):

The table has the border-radius well implemented, the problem is that you can't see it because you don't have a border setted for the table.
The code will be something like this:

```
.tableContainer {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    width: 1340px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin-left: 18px;
}

.tableContainer>table  {
    border-radius:20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.tableContainer>table th {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.tableContainer>table td {
    border: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tableContainer table::after  {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    right: -20px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Comment: I have tested it on codepen and it works like charm! :)